# I want to avoid the amount of if-statements I have

Tags: java, if-statement

In my code I have the user input and something I want printed to them.

For example:

```
If their input is "1", output "one",
If their input is "2", output "two",
If their input is "3", output "three",
If their input is "4", output "four"
```

And so on. How would I be able to make this but without using so many if-statements.

Comment: Store all the words in an array, convert their input to a number and use it as the array index

Comment: It sounds like time to learn about `Map`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use keyword 'switch'

```
switch (their input) {
  case "1": output "one";
  case "2": output "two";
  case "3": output "three";
  case "4": output "four";
}
```

I kept the pseudo langage stuff you were using, this is not a working code

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it from pseudo code into actual code and it works!

Comment: Don't forget the break statements at the end of each case.

Comment: true, I assumed output was a return :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use map for this

Note: `Map.of()` from **JDK9+**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = Map.of("1", "one", "2", "two", "3", "three", "4", "four");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(map.get(input));
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it something they will have covered in programming 101?